# Did Craig Donovan ever time traveled with the sphere?

Tags: plot-explanation, time-travel, seven-days

Back in the day (1998-2001), there was airing a sci-fi classic called [Seven Days](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167720/) of which I watched a few episodes where an ex-CIA agent Frank Parker is recruited by a top-secret government organization to travel 7 days back in time to fix the timeline. The traveling is done via a mysterious sphere of unknown origin and Frank is the only chrononaut crazy to withstand the pain threshold associated with the jumps.

Recently, I had time to re-watch it properly, but I believe I maybe missed some episode because I would swear that when this was airing, Frank's buddy and substitute chrononaut, Craig Donovan, was at least once traveling with a sphere 7 days back in time because for some reason Frank couldn't.

Therefore my question is: did Craig Donovan ever time travel as Frank's substitute or not?

Comment: ID questions are off-topic.

Comment: Technically not an ID question, he is not asking what is this, or find that, he is asking a plot question, though if you watched it and know he didn't then asking others won't change that.

Comment: Wiki says no: " In spite of his 'backup' status, the series never depicts him taking Frank's place. He has, on occasion, assumed command of the project, its security forces, and the scientific branch during the end-of-the world situations that frequently precede a backstep as project leaders were killed or incapacitated. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asks:

> *Did Craig Donovan ever time traveled with the sphere?*

According to the following article, and the wiki entry, the answer is no:

> One of those problems may be the fact that Donovan, as second banana, has never been able to backstep on the series.
>
> "It's never going to happen," Franklin says. "It's a mandate."
>
> Donovan has a unique distinction: he has been killed the most times on the series.

https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-2001-04-11-0104110035-story.html

> "I pretty regularly read the newsgroup postings. It's just fascinating the attention people pay to the show. It's kind of nice we have intelligent viewers.
>
> "A lot of the problems that we as actors have with the show and its logic and its departures from logic in many cases -- the fans pick up on it."

Also, wiki says:

> " In spite of his 'backup' status, the series never depicts him taking Frank's place. He has, on occasion, assumed command of the project, its security forces, and the scientific branch during the end-of-the world situations that frequently precede a backstep as project leaders were killed or incapacitated. "

Comment: Should be plenty of spare Franks around anyway, since versions of him keep arriving from the future.